# Change endianess of bluetooth transfer

Tags: objective-c, ios, endianness, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using bluetooth 4 (Low Energy) and need to transfer an 8-bit slider value to my slave device. The receiving end should get something like this : `000000A3` but right now I am stuck with `A3000000`

I have tried different solutions:

```
int value = ((int)slider.value >> 24) ;
NSData *dataToWrite = [NSData dataWithBytes:&value length:4]; //data to be sent has to be of type NSData
```

and

```
int value[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, slider.value};
```

and the only working one

```
char value[4] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, slider.value};
```

but I think this looks a bit ugly. Any other ideas on how to do this?

Comment: honestly not a bad solution - only one line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Foundation has functions for handling byte-order conversions: [Byte-Order Utilities Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/Reference/reference.html)